# I want to do a full join in Power Query with 8 tables but want new records in matching columns to be inserted into the bottom of the table

Tags: excel, powerquery

As an example heres:

[image: Table 1]

and here's

[image: Table 2]

and I want it to add rows not found in table 2, to the bottom of table 1, like this

[image: Table 3]

I can do a full join in R and it works, but cant figure out how to do it in power query

Comment: Check here how to join two tables with multiple columns: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/11/14/excel-join-tables-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

Append one table to the other (Home ... Append queries...)
Highlight the relevant columns upon which to match
Right click. Remove duplicates.

```
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"PriorStepName", OtherTable}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Appended Query")
```

Another way

Start in Table2.

Merge in Table1, matching all columns, using Left
Anti-join as merge type

That just leaves items in Table2 not found in Table1

Remove extra column

Append Table1

So in Table2... assuming two columns to match named **Column1** and **Column2**

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"PriorStepName",{"Column1", "Column2"},Table1,{"Column1", "Column2"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftAnti),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Table1"}),
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Columns", Table1})
```

Comment: My merge involves 8 tables so is there a way to summarize the steps so that I can quickly do it with all 8?

Comment: Use the first version, and append all 8 tables together. Then remove duplicates.